# Unknown Entity in multithreading hibernate

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

We are converting a large database from one DBMS to another. We are mostly using JDBC for this but there are some Hibernate calls mixed in. So far, a small portion of the database is taking seven hours to migrate. To mitigate this, we decided we could migrate different parts of the database simultaneously. We rewrote the migration routine to use threads. After wading through Java heap space issues and making sure we had separate JDBC and Hibernate sessions in each thread, we found ourselves with one last problem: We are getting Unknown entity: exceptions everywhere. We are creating a SchemaExport and executing it before any migration thread starts. What are we missing?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of that exception?

Comment: We solved our own problem. We were not creating a session in the first part where we created the schema Export. Once we did that, everything else fell into line.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Unknown entity is an exception which happens when hibernate doesn't know about the class which is referenced in the exception.
e.g., for the `Myclass` class:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: data.Myclass
```

You need to have a `<classname>.hbm.xml` file, which corresponds to a hibernate mapping, in order for each class that must be known by hibernate, and also have these files referenced as resources in the main configuration file of hibernate.
in `hibernate.cfg.xml`, this is the line to let hibernate know about the class `Myclass`:

```
<mapping resource="Myclass.hbm.xml" />
```